# How do I create a virtual machine with a disk size different than the default?

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware

I'm trying to create a virtual machine for Windows 7 x64. However VMWare Fusion automatically decides that the disk size can be 60GB and no smaller.

How do I create a virtual machine with a smaller disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are done with the wizard, right click on the VM and select "settings" then pick "Hard Disk" then you should be able to move the cursor left and right to adjust the size of the disk.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. After clicking 'Install OS X from the recovery partition' it decides to create everything for me and absolutely nothing works to decrease the stupid disk size.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare Fusion (which I'm assuming you're using since you're posting in the Apple section) has some presets for disk space depending on the OS (20 GB for Linux, 60 GB for Windows, and 40 GB for OS X) when you create a new virtual machine. There are two ways around this:

**Option 1: Create your own virtual disk**

1. Run

```sh
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmware-vdiskmanager -c -t 0 -s 20GB -a ide myDisk.vmdk
```

to create a new virtual disk.   Replace "20GB" with your desired size and "myDisk.vmdk" with the desired name and path of your new disk.

2. When creating the machine in VMWare Fusion, in the "Choose a Virtual Disk" screen, check the option to use an existing virtual disk.

   > [image: VMWare Disk Selection]

**Option 2: Resize before installing**
You can also resize the newly created virtual disk **before** the OS is installed.

1. Set up your VM as normal, accepting the default disk size for now.
2. When you get to this screen, click "Customize Settings":

   > [image: Customize Settings]
3. Save the VM
4. In the Settings window, click "Hard Disk (SCSI)"
5. Resize your disk as needed and click "Apply"

   > [image]

Comment: This seems a little more complicated than I would like, but atleast it shows me how to create a virtual disk. ;)